# FullCalendar - update resources businessHours

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Need some help, with fullcalendar business hour update.

My code :

```
$.each(json_resource, function(index,value){

  var businessHours = { 
    dow: [ value.dow ], 
    start: value.start, 
    end: value.end 
  }

  // GET RESOURCE OBJECT
  var resourceObject = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getResourceById', value.resourceId );

  // ADD NEW BUSINESS WORKING HOUR
  resourceObject.businessHours = businessHours;

  // UPDATE HOURS
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'option', 'resources', resourceObject);

});
```

The problem is **$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'option', 'resources', events);** it freeze windows for some seconds. Maybe there is another solution for updating resource business hours ?

Comment: this doesn't make a lot of sense. You loop through all your events, and create a "businessHours". Then you try to assign it to a single resource. object. If you have 20 events in the same resource, it will update that resource's business hours 20 times with different values each time depending on what was in the event. Doesn't seem very logical. You'll always end up with the businessHours of the last event in the loop for that resource. Shouldn't the businessHours of each resource be pre-defined, and delivered when you create the calendar, not dependent on the events within the resource??

Comment: @ADyson it's not getting all events, it getting all resource. I have 10 resource, and var events just name, it getting resources not events. And i need to loop every time it change date, because every day has different working time and json_events it's not events, it resource object with working time.

Comment: why did you call the variable "events" then??? Designed to confuse everyone! Especially when fullCalendar also has a key concept called events. If "json_events" is a list of resources then the code still makes no sense because a resource doesn't have "start" or "end" properties that you can read. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/Resource_Object/

Comment: Also I still don't understand why you don't just define all this before you create the calendar. There's a lack of context here. You've got a list of resources. Are these the same resources you loaded into the calendar? Why haven't they got the businessHours already defined?

Comment: @ADyson one more time, my staff (resource in day view) have different working time every day, so I can't specified all year working time in businessHour. So then I change date I need to check staff (resource) working time and update it (my code works (but it freeze windows for some seconds)) . And please look here resource have start end businessHours https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/businessHours-per-resource/ (my resource have start and end). So this is not the problem. The problem is, how can I update businessHour different not with option. (I UPDATE NAME)

Comment: ok with a bit more context that makes more sense. I'm not sure why it would take several seconds to update, presumably that's some internal code of fullCalendar. You could try debugging the un-minified version to see where the delay is and maybe submit a bug to the maintainer. In the meantime, have you considered using background events for this purpose instead? You can achieve the same visual effect but vary the times by day exactly as you require, with no custom code - you could supply the data with the main event feed. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

Comment: @ADyson ok i just rewrite my code with rendering background, and it's more faster, no freezing. You can submit your answer I will accept it :) Thanks.

Comment: done, thankyou :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would take several seconds to update, presumably that's some internal code of fullCalendar. You could try debugging the un-minified version to see where the delay is and maybe submit a bug to the maintainer.

In the meantime, consider using Background Events for this purpose instead. You can achieve the same visual effect but vary the times by day exactly as you require, with no custom code - you could supply the data with the main event feed. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events for details

Answer (score 1):

You can update the businessHours array in viewRender event:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    view.calendar.businessHourGenerator.rawComplexDef = [your BusinessHours array]
}
```